# How can I enable user to dynamically set logo in Apex 5?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I need to allow the user upload a number of logos and select a default, that will then become the logo that's shown at the top left of the screen.

Usually the logo is a static application file, so is there perhaps a way to make changes to those by the user? Or to set a static file as a select statement?

I also tried setting an application computation to set an application item but couldn't get that to work.

This is my first question on SO. If I'm asking something stupid, please go easy on me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to solve this problem is to give the user a page for him to upload and manage the logos. (save them in the database)

Then create a RESTful Web Service that returns the image of a selected logo,
and use the link of the RESTful Web Service as the img src link.